# React.js - Using one component multiple times with different settings

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a re-usable component that wraps similar functionality where the only things that change are a Title string and the data that is used to populate a Kendo ComboBox.

So, I have a navigation menu that loads (at the moment) six different filters:

```
{ 
     context && context.Filters && context.Filters.map((item) => getComponent(item))
}
```

GetComponent gets the ID of the filter, gets the definition of the filter from the context, and creates a drop down component passing in properties:

```
function getComponent(item) {
    var filterDefinition = context.Filters.find(filter => filter.Id === item.Id);

    switch (item.DisplayType) {
      case 'ComboBox':
        return <DropDownFilterable key={item.Id} Id={item.Id} Definition={filterDefinition} />
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

The DropDownFilterable component calls a service to get the data for the combo box and then loads everything up:

```
const DropDownFilterable = (props) => {
  const appService = Service();

  filterDefinition = props.Definition;
  console.log(filterDefinition.Name + " - " + filterDefinition.Id);

  React.useEffect(() => {
         console.log("useEffect: " + filterDefinition.Name + " - " + filterDefinition.Id);
         appService.getFilterValues(filterDefinition.Id).then(response => {
         filterData = response;
  })
}, []); 

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row" title={filterDefinition.DisplayName}>{filterDefinition.DisplayName}</div>
      <ComboBox 
          id={"filterComboBox_" + filterDefinition.Id}
          data={filterData}
          //onOpen={console.log("test")}
          style={{zIndex: 999999}}
          dataItemKey={filterDefinition && filterDefinition.Definition && filterDefinition.Definition.DataHeaders[0]}
          textField={filterDefinition && filterDefinition.Definition && filterDefinition.Definition.DataHeaders[1]}
        />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Service call:

```
  function getFilterValues(id) {
    switch(id) {
      case "E903B2D2-55DE-4FA3-986A-8A038751C5CD":
        return fetch(Settings.url_getCurrencies).then(toJson);
      default:
        return fetch(Settings.url_getRevenueScenarios).then(toJson);
    }
  };
```

What's happening is, the title (DisplayName) for each filter is correctly rendered onto the navigation menu, but the data for all six filters is the data for whichever filter is passed in last. I'm new to React and I'm not 100% comfortable with the hooks yet, so I'm probably doing something in the wrong order or not doing something in the right hook. I've created a slimmed-down version of the app:

https://codesandbox.io/s/spotlight-react-full-forked-r25ns

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using `filterData` incorrectly - you defined it outside of the `DropDownFilterable` component which means it will be shared. Instead, set the value in component state (*I've shortened the code to include just my changes*):

```js
const DropDownFilterable = (props) => {
  // ...

  // store filterData in component state
  const [filterData, setFilterData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // ...
    appService.getFilterValues(filterDefinition.Id).then(response => {
      // update filterData with response from appService
      setFilterData(response);
    })
  }, []); 

  // only show a ComboBox if filterData is defined
  return filterData && (
    // ...
  )
}
```

Alternatively you can use an empty array as the default state...

```
const [filterData, setFilterData] = React.useState([]);
```

...since the `ComboBox` component accepts an array for the `data` prop. That way you won't have to conditionally render.

---

**Update**

For `filterDefinition` you also need to make sure it is set properly:

```js
const [filterDefinition, setFilterDefinition] = React.useState(props.Definition);

// ...

React.useEffect(() => {
  setFilterDefinition(props.Definition);
}, [props.Definition]);
```

It may also be easier to keep `filterDefinition` out of state if you don't expect it to change:

```js
const filterDefinition = props.Definition || {};
```

Comment: Thanks. This results in too many re-renders (React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop). If I recall correctly this is why I took the filterData out of state. I've updated the codesandbox app if you want to see it and can help. I appreciate it!

Comment: Now you have a problem with `filterDefinition` - you are setting state on every render. Wrap that with another `useEffect` and make sure `props.Definition` is in the dependency array. See my edit. You should avoid updating state directly in the function body as that means you are updating state on every render.

Comment: Ahh..that did it. Thank you so much. I didn't know you could have multiple useEffect hooks.